# trouble with passing a string pointer and then checking size in a constructor/method

Tags: c++, string, object

I'm still learning about strings, but I'm trying to use them more often. How could I get something like this to work? I'm not even sure where to start
(yes, this is an object. I'm also learning about these atm for an assignment)

```
MyClass::MyClass(string* newName)
{
  if (newName.length() > maxNameLength) //maxNameLength = 50
  {  
     //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not need the pointer bit - try `MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& newName)`

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you. Now I have to try and understand why.

Comment: Go and spend some time reading a book on C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little explanation as to use

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& newName)
```

1. You do not need a pointer to the string. A reference is better - hence `&`
2. Your constructor should not be modifying this string - tell both the compiler and the developer - hence `const`
3. Do not pollute your namespace - hence `std::`
4. DO NOT USE `using std` (see 3)

Comment: can you explain exactly this namespace std stuff? I found that I don't always put "std::string str1" just "string str1", is that bad practice?

and if so, should I be using a char. As you can imagine, my class has a private data member that is "string name", hence why I'm calling my constructor to change it.

Comment: If you are able to do `string str1` then somewhere somebody (maybe you) has a line `using std`. This pollutes the namespace as it includes a lot of stuff. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice etc

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Ed's answer:

If you really want to use a pointer, your constructor should look like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string* const newName)
{
  if (newName!=nullptr && newName->length() > maxNameLength) //maxNameLength = 50
  {  
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Not the `operator->` to call `length()`. You can skip one of the `const` qualifiers if you either need to change the pointer or its content.

Anyway, using references is usually the better alternative.

Comment: The problem is - What happens if you pass a null pointer? Better to have the compiler pick that one up

Comment: good point, added that. As i said, using references is usually the better way to do this....

Comment: Perhaps an `assert`?

Comment: Since the OP didn't give us any information about his actions if the string exceeds maxLength, i just decided to check for nullptr and if so to not "//do stuff"